# Spring Hibernate annotation based master details data save error

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring framework. I am trying to insert a department with some personnel in database. I am using spring-mvc and Hibernate to do so. I am following [this article to implement](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/), but I am not creating the table by SQL. The table are creating on application runtime. I am using PostgreSQL. Here are my attempts below.

My department entity class:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="department_id")
    private Long departmentId;
    
    @Column(name="department_name")
    private String departmentName;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    @IndexColumn(name="idx")
    private List<Personnel> personnels;

    public Long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public List<Personnel> getPersonnels() {
        return personnels;
    }

    public void setPersonnels(List<Personnel> personnels) {
        this.personnels = personnels;
    }
```

My personnel entity class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="personnel")
public class Personnel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="personnel_id")
    private Long personnelId;
    
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;
    
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    
    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;
    
    @Column(name="cell_phone")
    private String cellphone;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id", 
                insertable=false, updatable=false, 
                nullable=false)
    private Department department; 
    
    @Column(name="idx")
    private Integer idx;
    
    public Personnel() {
        
    }
    
    public Personnel(String firstname, String lastname, String phone) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.cellphone = phone;
    }

}
```

My controller save action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String save(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> department = request.getParameterMap();
    Map<String, String> data = departmentService.insert(department);
    System.out.println("######### >> Data Saved with id :: " + data.get("id"));
    return "redirect:/department/show/" + data.get("id");
}
```

My service insert action:

```
public Map<String, String> insert(Map<String, String[]> map) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Long id = null;
    Department department = new Department();
    department.setDepartmentName(map.get("departmentName")[0]);
    department.setPersonnels(new ArrayList<Personnel>());
    
    Personnel emp1 = new Personnel("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
    Personnel emp2 = new Personnel("Tony", "Almeida", "222");
    
    department.getPersonnels().add(emp1);
    department.getPersonnels().add(emp2);
    
    id = departmentDao.insertDoc(department);
    params.put("id", id.toString());
    return params ;
    
}
```

My dao insertDoc action:

```
@Transactional
public Long insertDoc(Department doc) {
    Long id = (Long) sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().save(doc);
    sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    return id;
}
```

And finally the error I get:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [testSpring] in context with path [/testSpring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "department_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (16, 2016-08-27, 111, Nina, null, Mayers, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at com.stock.dao.DepartmentDao.insertDoc(DepartmentDao.java:23)
    at com.stock.dao.DepartmentDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$132caf1f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.stock.dao.DepartmentDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36cc6e45.insertDoc(<generated>)
    at com.stock.service.DepartmentService.insert(DepartmentService.java:34)
    at com.stock.controller.DepartmentController.save(DepartmentController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is showing null value problem in department_id. How can I solve it with this code block?

Answer (score 1):

you also need to set department in Personnel also rest of the thing will be take care by hibernate .:

eg :

```
public Map<String, String> insert(Map<String, String[]> map) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Long id = null;
    Department department = new Department();
    department.setDepartmentName(map.get("departmentName")[0]);
    department.setPersonnels(new ArrayList<Personnel>());

    Personnel emp1 = new Personnel("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
    Personnel emp2 = new Personnel("Tony", "Almeida", "222");

// Set Department in your emp1 and emp2 object 
    emp1.setDepartment(department);
    emp2.setDepartment(department);

    department.getPersonnels().add(emp1);
    department.getPersonnels().add(emp2);

    id = departmentDao.insertDoc(department);
    params.put("id", id.toString());
    return params ;

}
```

change log :

```
// Set Department in your emp1 and emp2 object 
        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        emp2.setDepartment(department);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully:

> ERROR: null value in column "department_id" violates not-null constraint

Your `department_id` column in the `department` table has a non null constraint, which is being violated when you try to insert the following entity using Hibernate:

```
Department department = new Department();
department.setDepartmentName(map.get("departmentName")[0]);
department.setPersonnels(new ArrayList<Personnel>());
```

You never assign the ID, which is defaulting to `NULL`, causing the error you are seeing.  To remedy this, assign a non null ID to the department before inserting:

```
department.setDepartmentId(1L);   // or any value you wish
```

Comment: will it not be a static value then? I mean the - departmentId?!

Comment: Obviously you need to put the correct id there OR make it nullable. Either a person ALWAYS must have a department - then you must give an id - or not. You cannot declare the department to be needed and then not give one. And insertable=false, updatable=false will probably interfere there, too.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. But same error. no luck

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I just followed the blog to save a master details value in database as it suggests. But no luck

Comment: Did you rebuild and redeploy your code after making the change?